# React Popover Not working - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className')

Tags: c#, reactjs, popover

Trying to implement popover from example. but not getting where it went wrong.

Method implemented.

```
Overlay = () => {
    const popover = () => (
        <Popover id="popover-basic">
            <Popover.Title as="h3">Popover right</Popover.Title>
            <Popover.Content>
                And here's some <strong>amazing</strong> content. It's very engaging.
                right?
            </Popover.Content>
        </Popover>
    );
    return popover;
}
```

and calling like this

```
<OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="right" overlay={() => this.Overlay()}>
                        <Button variant="success" >see</Button>
                    </OverlayTrigger>
```

Error:
[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76429142/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Issues with your code:

1. You're defining `Overlay` as a functional component, but you're returning the function `popover` instead of the JSX markup
2. You're invoking `this.Overlay()` as if it was class method, but it should be treated as a regular function component.

Modify the code like this:

```
const Overlay =  (
        <Popover id="popover-basic">
            <Popover.Title as="h3">Popover right</Popover.Title>
            <Popover.Content>
                And here's some <strong>amazing</strong> content. It's very engaging.
                right?
            </Popover.Content>
        </Popover>
    );
}
```

And invoke like this:

```
<OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="right" overlay={Overlay}>
    <Button variant="success" >see</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```